# Multiple valued attribute within same object using one to many relationship in Django

Tags: django, django-models, one-to-many

I have to create a registration app using Django. There will be two models: Event, consisting of event name and fees; and Participant, consisting of participant details and the event in which they have participated. One participant may have participated in multiple events. 
While saving the objects I do not want multiple entries for different events of the same participant. I suppose this implies the use of a one to many relationship field, which I am unable to find in Django. 
The schema I tried was

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_limit=50)
    fees = models.IntegerField(default=100)

class Participant (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_limit=50)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    receiptno = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

I tried using Foreign key field but it is able to store only one event the participant has participated in. I want to be able to store multiple events in one participant object (as only one receipt was issued manually per participant irrespective of the events participated in) How do I do the same?

Comment: use [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a many-to-many relationship, not a one-to-many one. Specifically, you want one with a through model, which would record the receipt number.

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_limit=50)
    event = models.ManyToManyField('Event', through='Receipt')

class Receipt(models.Model):
    receiptno = models.IntegerField()
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event')
    participant = models.ForeignKey('Participant')
```

Comment: Okay, but doesn't this make the process of creating objects tedious? Like despite having only 1 participant per receipt no, I need to enter associated data at two locations? Means first entering the participant detail, then entering the receipt detail. Is there a way to do this in one form on admin side?

Comment: Sure, you can use Receipt as an inline admin form alongside Participant.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, and thanks for the answer! For every event participant has participated in, I need to have a 'Participated' Boolean data member. Where shall I accommodate it in this structure?

Comment: I'm not sure what for - surely the existence of the event in the participant's event list is enough? But if you do, you can put it on the Receipt model as well.